# Let $A$ be a vector perpendicular to every $X$. Show that $A$=$0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

*Proposition.* Let $A$ be a vector perpendicular to every $X$. Show that $A$=$0$.

I think that proof of this is obvious by the definiton, isn't it?

*Definition.* We define two vectors $A,B$ to be **perpendicular** (or as we shall also say, **orthogonal**), if $A.B$=$0$.

Comment: If $A$ is perpendicular to everything then $A\cdot A=0$.

Comment: A better exercise would be: Let $V$ be a vector space and $\alpha$ a basis. Suppose that $v$ is orthogonal to any basis vector, show that $v=0$.

Comment: Note that this is still true even for nondegenerate bilinear forms of indefinite signature, in which case $A \cdot A = 0$ need not imply $A = 0 $.

Comment: @hayyam It’s simple, but I’m not sure I’d call it obvious. Vector multiplication doesn’t behave like scalar multiplication. In particular, if you have $A\cdot B=0$, you can’t immediately conclude that $A=0$ or $B=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say perpendicular, your vector space should be equipped with an inner product.

One requirement for inner product is

$$<u,u>=0 \iff u=0$$

So your $A$ is perpendicular to every $X$, and so

$$<A,A>=0$$

Hence, $A=0$.